# Bean property 'entityManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method (using Spring and Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Spring and hibernate are both new tools for me and I struggle a bit using both at the same time.

spring.xml :

```
<bean id="my.supervisionFramesProcess" class="supervision.frames.SupervisionFramesProcess"
    init-method="startup" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="SupervisionDAO">
        <bean class="supervision.dao.jpa.JpaSupervisionDao">
            <property name="entityManager" ref="my.entity-manager-factory"     />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="my.dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://XXXX/supervision?autoReconnect=true" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>

<bean id="my.entity-manager-factory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="my.dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SUPERVISION-1.0" />
</bean>
```

JpaSupervisionDao.xml :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "SUPERVISION-1.0")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public JpaSupervisionDao() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("New instance DAO : " + this);
}
protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@Override
public SupervisionDbObject selectSupervisionDbObject(SupervisionDbObject supervision) {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(SELECT_SUPERVISION);
}
```

persistence.xml :

```
<persistence-unit name="SUPERVISION-1.0">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>supervision.dao.SupervisionDbObject</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Using JDBC, my DataSource can be instanciated and is fully working but using Hibernate and the entityManager, i only get an error :

```
Bean property 'entityManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
```

I have tried to use the EntityManagerFactory object instead but the same error occurs.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Your `setEntityManager` is `protected`. However you should remove it and let the `@PersistenceContext` do its work. Make sure you have a `<context:annotation-config />` in your configuration.

Comment: Do I really need the <context: annotation-config /> if i have already a bean like the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor ? ( Added in op)

Comment: No you don't, but the `<context:annotation-config/>` does more then only the `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (like `@Autowired`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of the `<context:annotation-config/>` fixed my issue thanks to M. Deinum's answer.

If this can help someone else, I also had an issue with an import, I was importing 
`org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` instead of `javax.persistence.Entity`.